# concatenar 2 array con condicion en python

Tags: python, array

Tengo 2 array, de 2 columnas cada una.  El array A tiene la forma:

```
pid                track

0        77vFvcdWZi0ZqiDOoHU3YI 
1        0e9hR1vTrzlUvFH5PgA9rY 
2        00z4wF0iJsp6GwDkQxkGs6 
3        0CyRloqqjpeKEAd3cO6J6z 
4        0c1gHntWjKD7QShC8s99sq
...      .....
```

mientras que el array B es:

```
     diccionario                  id
0UaMYEvWZi0ZqiDOoHU3YI            34
0e9hR1vTrzlUvFH5PgA9rY             3
00z4wF0iJsp6GwDkQxkGs6             1 
0CyRloqqjpeKEAd3cO6J6z             2
0c1gHntWjKD7QShC8s99sq            16
...      .....
```

necesito un  array  C, donde el id de dicho arreglo sea el id del diccionario del  array B que corresponda al track del arreglo A, osea, de la forma:

```
pid                 id
 0                  22 
 1                   3
 2                   1
 3                   2
 4                  16
...                .....
```

Pero no se como hacerlo en python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si puedes usar la biblioteca pandas, siempre recomendable para tratar con datos estructurados en tablas como es tu caso, la solución pasa por:

1. Cargar cada una de tus tablas en un dataframe pandas
2. Usar como índice la columna "track" en la tabla 1, y la columna "diccionario" en la tabla 2.
3. Hacer un `join()` de ambas tablas. Pandas se ocupa de "hacer encajar" las filas con el mismo índice.
4. Como consecuencia del paso anterior pueden aparecer valores "NaN" (que son una especie de valores nulos) en elementos que tengan índice en una de las tablas pero no en la otra. Opcionalmente puedes cambiar esos "NaN" por cualquier otro valor (cero, o una cadena de guiones, etc.)
5. El resultado del join usará como índice los hashes esos que sirvieron para hacer la mezcla. Si no los quieres puedes hacer un `reset_index()` al resultado
6. También opcionalmente puedes fijar como índice del resultado la columna `pid`.

El siguiente fragmento hace los pasos 1 y 2. En este caso las tablas las "leo" de cadenas, puesto que me resulta más cómodo hacerlo así simplemente copiando y pegando el ejemplo de tu pregunta. En tu caso las leerías probablemente de fichero. Pandas puede leer csv y excel y otros muchos formatos.

**Edición**: Por cierto, he desordenado las filas del array B para que después se vea mejor que `.join()` no se limita a concatenar "en horizontal", sino que realmente "busca" en B los elementos basándose en los índices.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

datos1 = """\
pid                track
0        77vFvcdWZi0ZqiDOoHU3YI 
1        0e9hR1vTrzlUvFH5PgA9rY 
2        00z4wF0iJsp6GwDkQxkGs6 
3        0CyRloqqjpeKEAd3cO6J6z 
4        0c1gHntWjKD7QShC8s99sq"""

datos2 = """\
     diccionario                  id
0CyRloqqjpeKEAd3cO6J6z             2
00z4wF0iJsp6GwDkQxkGs6             1 
0c1gHntWjKD7QShC8s99sq            16
0e9hR1vTrzlUvFH5PgA9rY             3
0UaMYEvWZi0ZqiDOoHU3YI            34"""

a = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(datos1), sep=r'\s+').set_index("track")
b = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(datos2), sep=r'\s+').set_index("diccionario")
```

El siguiente fragmento hace los pasos 3 y 4 (relleno los valores desconocidos con un "-"):

```
c = a.join(b).fillna("-")
print(c)
```

```
                        pid  id
track                          
77vFvcdWZi0ZqiDOoHU3YI    0   -
0e9hR1vTrzlUvFH5PgA9rY    1   3
00z4wF0iJsp6GwDkQxkGs6    2   1
0CyRloqqjpeKEAd3cO6J6z    3   2
0c1gHntWjKD7QShC8s99sq    4  16
```

El siguiente código haría los pasos 5 y 6, es decir, elimina el índice "track" y pone `pid` como nuevo índice, dando ya el resultado buscado:

```
c = c.reset_index(drop=True).set_index("pid")
print(c)
```

```
     id
pid    
0     -
1     3
2     1
3     2
4    16
```

Comment: El problema que tengo es que en el diccionario (array B) aparecen todos los track con su id, pero los track están agrupados por pid en array A. Entonces lo que necesito es que el track del array A, busque su id en la array B. No se si me explique bien.?

Comment: @Skiel Sí, creo que te he entendido. Y eso es lo que hace `join()`. ¿No ves cómo al `pid=1` le asigna el `id=3` porque en ambos concuerda el "track" con el "diccionario"? En mi ejemplo el elemento con `pid=0` no tiene asociado `id` porque en el array B no hay valor de "diccionario" que coincida con su "track" (porque no tengo los datos completos)

Comment: @Skiel Si la solución que te he dado no funciona en tus datos completos por alguna razón que no estoy entendiendo, añade a la pregunta el caso que te da problemas para que pueda entenderlo mejor

Comment: @Skiel Acabo de editar la respuesta para desordenar el array B y que veas cómo sigue funcionando, a ver si así entiendes mejor qué hace `.join()`